# Yii2 route config if controller inside folder?

Tags: routes, controller, yii2

[image]

This image are my yii2 project structure, I already config routes to access these controllers, some routes with controller in top level of controller folder working well (green color), but not working in controller inside sub folder (red color).

**The goal**

URL (green color): `/{storeId}/{controller}/{action}` -> working well

URL (Red color): `/{storeId}/{folder}/{controller}/{action}` -> **not working (show not found message)**

How to solve this Problem?, I have no idea and already search on Google but no luck.

**Solved**

```
    '<module:(product|report)>/<controller>/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/<controller>/view',
    '<module:(product|report)>/<controller>/<action>/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
    '<module:(product|report)>/<controller>/<action>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
```

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: yes it is.. already solved, i've edited my question with solving code. btw thanks to answer

Comment: Great. Could you upvote my answer? I suggested to use modules also. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As a convention in Yii all controllers are stored in the same directory, namely `controllers`, you can not use subdirectories. However you could use **modules**. In your directory structure:

```
...
controllers
models
modules
  product
    controllers
      InboundController.php
      OutboundController.php
    models
    Module.php
    views
  report
    controllers
      PurchaseController.php
      SalesController.php
      StockController.php
    models
    Module.php
    views
runtime
...
```

See [Yii documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-modules). Configure Module.php, bootstrapping as described there.

You can use the the following routing in your routes.php:

```
'<store:\w+>/<module:\w+>/<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>'
```